# SqlDataReader not returning any rows when I use a select statement with a where clause

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

```
using(var conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=" + path + @"\" + dbName + ";Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30"))
{
    conn.Open();
    var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [Staff_Enroll] WHERE Fingerprint = '@fingerprint' ", conn);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("fingerprint", val);
    var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    while (reader.Read())
    {
        Staff_finger = Convert.ToString(reader["Department"]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please describe your problem, and what you tried, not only copy-paste a code.

Comment: you have this line `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("fingerprint", val);` yet you add the parameter `fingerprint` vs `@fingerprint` read up on parameters in SQL and how to construct parameterized query's in C#. please post the error as I am quite sure it's returning one

Comment: @MethodMan SqlParameter automatically adds the @ if it is missing

Comment: @MethodMan [Line 549 of the internal property SqlParameter.ParameterNameFixed does it](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/System.Data/R/e0b0ddfdcb0fca98.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you have enclosed the parameter name in quotes. Remove those:

```
var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [Staff_Enroll] WHERE Fingerprint = @fingerprint;", conn);
```

Also, I suggest you [avoid AddWithValue](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and use explicitly-typed parameters instead. That will help improve performance and avoid surprises.